# Compiler writing in C: How to use libyasm to compile a generated assembly file at runtime?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction

How can I use `libyasm` library to compile an assembly file which is generated at runtime, to an executable? This assembly file is the generated output of a compiler written in C and I want to output an executable instead of a `.S` output file.

I tried to google but couldn't find anything useful.

P.S: Also let me know if there is any other suitable alternative.

Comment: Have you tried to read [the reference](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/reference/libyasm-doc/html/files.html)? It's linked to from [the libyasm wiki](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/wiki/Libyasm) which was the *first* link in my search for "libyasm".

Comment: It's *much* simpler to just fork+exec a stand-alone assembler (like `/usr/bin/yasm`).  Also note that NASM/YASM syntax files are more usually called `.asm`, while compiler-generate GNU syntax files are called `.s` (lower-case).  Hand-written `.S` files are fed to the C preprocessor first, then to `as`, so they can use AT&T syntax, or (with `.intel_syntax noprefix`) GAS's MASM-like syntax (but still GNU directives, like `.globl main`, not `global main`)

Comment: Yes @Someprogrammerdude. It's raw source code without any help on how to star. I can read the whole source code and find out how this is possible but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes: But then everyone who wants to use my compiler needs to install `yasm`! Any solution?

Comment: If you think writing out an asm file and then running an assembler on it sounds silly, then keep in mind that's exactly what GCC does.  (It has a `-pipe` option to pipe the asm through the assembler instead of writing `/tmp/random-number.s`)

Comment: Well just bundle a YASM executable with your compiler!  Software packages can and do include multiple executables.  But fair point, it works well for GCC + binutils where you already need multiple executables.  If it's easy, then sure, go for YASM as a library.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point. If it doesn't have any additional dependency it would be a good idea. I will give it a try

Comment: There have been previous SO questions about embedding an assembler into something else, (where the answer was a suggestion to try libyasm).  While digging up that suggestion as an answer, I saw a few warning signs on the libyasm web page. It looked like maybe making it fully usable for programs other than yasm itself was more of an unfinished project than a real thing. I'd say do it the quick & dirty way for now, and put libyasm on your TODO list of things to investigate. You'll want your compiler to emit real asm for debugging purposes, and you really want to be able to trust your assembler..

Comment: If you do get back to this, it would be really neat if you can show some sample code that uses libyasm to assemble a string from a `char*`, producing an object file on disk and/or machine code in memory.  (Or if someone else can provide an answer like that, of course!)

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe it has already been done, it's called https://github.com/yasm/yasm/blob/master/frontends/yasm/yasm.c -- if you check, you'll see that all the includes are to libyasm.h or things in the libyasm/ tree